# Three.js - Translating vs Moving?

Tags: 3d, three.js, translation

Let's say I have a custom cube mesh, where the origin is at one of the corners.
I would like to specify the origin of the cube to be in the center of it.
I understand that I can do a translation, and it seems to work (I can prove it works by rotating the cube, which rotates about the mid-center point).

However, I've always thought that translation was simply moving to another point in 3D space (rather than setting the origin point).

Am I missing something or am I simply confusing 2 things which are actually the same thing?

*** To summarize ***

Note that if I want to move an object, I just simply update the position vector.
And applying a translation SEEMS to be updating the origin point.
My confusion comes from my understanding that a "translation" is just a fancy term for "moving" an object in 3D space.
Therefore, what exactly is a translation (moving in 3d space, or updating the origin point, or both)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A translation on geometry moves the origin:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, 0.5, 0 ) );
```

A translation on an Object3D moves the position:

```
var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
obj.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: Does the translate() method of the Geometry class change the origin as well?

Comment: Yes, that method's implementation is the same as the code above: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/8622b1938a627aa72d2c9c55858c1fda3632c9ec/src/core/Geometry.js#L162-L178

Comment: What about the translate method of object3D? obj.translateX(20) Is this function setting the position?